# Should I downvote non-answers?

Tags: discussion

When a non-answer is posted on a question, I know I should flag it as not an answer. Should I also downvote?

Comment: As with everything involving votes, it is really up to you. Votes are a personal expression of opinion about the quality/usefulness of the post. For me, personally, I downvote everything that I am flagging for removal. Obviously, if I'm flagging it for removal, it's of exceptionally low quality, which is the exact type of thing that I would downvote. But there's no requirement you do what I do. Just as long as you flag them, that's the important part, as that keeps the site clean.

Comment: We never know how long it will take for the answer to be deleted... so, when it's downvoted, it's not shown in the top if the sorting of answers is based on score (if there are other answers and the other answers have a score of 0)... so, I feel it's better to downvote as well when you flag. But, it's not mandatory to downvote.

Comment: What is the your definition of a non-answer? Can you provide one or more examples for illustration (real and/or made up)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum "I'm having this problem too, did you find a solution?", "John123's answer is wrong.", "I have a related question, what happens when you ABC the PDQ under Raffenburg radiation?", "How about them Mets?"